# Why does Python raise an exception when I save() a model instance into a MongoDB database?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-nonrel

I've been using [this tutorial](http://django-mongodb.org/tutorial.html) to experiment and start up my first Django app using MongoDB. In the tutorial, they build a simple Post class as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from djangotoolbox.fields import ListField

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = ListField()
    comments = ListField()
```

Pretty simple. They then lead me through building a Post object with:

```
post = Post.objects.create(
...     title='Hello MongoDB!',
...     text='Just wanted to drop a note from Django. Cya!',
...     tags=['mongodb', 'django'],
...     comments=['comment 1', 'comment 2']
... )
```

It immediately sends a rather long stack trace which I have [copied here](http://dpaste.com/hold/731874/). The final error is:

```
TypeError: encoder expected a mapping type but got: {<django.db.models.fields.CharField object at 0x2fc5f10>: 'Hello MongoDB!', <djangotoolbox.fields.ListField object at 0x2fccd10>: ['comment 1', 'comment 2'], '_id': ObjectId('4f8a22f8db0ee4386f000000'), <djangotoolbox.fields.ListField object at 0x2fcc750>: ['django', 'mongodb'], <django.db.models.fields.TextField object at 0x2fcc290>: 'text test'}
```

It seems to be expecting completely different data types, and I have no idea where to go on this. Google searches have turned up nothing of use. Any tips or solutions would be a boon.

Thanks,

ParagonRG

Edit: I have realized that it actually errors when the initial object is created with `Post.objects.create()` when I correctly follow the tutorial. I therefore have the same problem, but without the save() function.

Edit: Typing `pip freeze` to display the current installed Python packages in my virtual environment gives me:

```
Django==1.3.1
django-mongodb-engine==0.4.0
djangotoolbox==0.9.2
pymongo==2.1.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Comment: you dont have to save after running that line of code

Comment: @FrantzdyRomain I do indeed have to run save(). Querying with `Post.objects.all()` returns an empty list. The post object is not yet saved in the database; it is simply a variable until saved.

Comment: @FrantzdyRomain Ah, I am mistaken. I'll edit my question.

Comment: In your stack trace you have <django.db.models.fields.TextField object at 0x2fcc290>: 'text test' is that TextField in your Post Class? I dont see it here

Comment: It would be nice to have the full stacktrace to know who throws the exception exactly, not sure this is comming from MongoBD at all

Comment: @ClaudeVedovini I linked the stack trace in the question. It's here: http://dpaste.com/hold/731874/

Comment: @FrantzdyRomain TextField is a built-in Django model. I've run through quite a few test cases. The one in the stack trace is equivalent to the TextField posted here that says, 'Just wanted to drop a note from Django. Cya!'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried that with the exact setup described in the tutorial and couldn't reproduce this :-(

Are you sure you exactly followed the installation instructions? In particular, did you use the exact same repositories?

Which version of PyMongo are you using?

Comment: I've edited my answer to display the output of `pip freeze` so you can see the software versions I'm using. The only difference between my setup and the setup linked in that tutorial is that I have since been told (by a major contributor to the project) to use the github repos instead of the ones found on bitbucket. I will run through the installation again to look for any other discrepancies.

Comment: I ran through the process again. It appears that I used .git extension last time, when it does not say to do so in the instructions. It gave me, on install, the following error output: http://dpaste.com/732106/. For good measure I tried to do create and save a Post object again, but it threw the same error as it did in my SO question writeup.

Comment: Just go with the bitbucket version. The GitHub code doesn't differ from what's on bitbucket (apart from the 'devel' branches which is unstable).

Answer (score 0):

save() is usually used when making changes to an model object or creating one.This url should get you going. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Please see my edits. I made a mistake; it actually errors on the initial creation of the object. Save() does not need to be called here, as you say.